# Wants to search the fileld value from Contract record in Purchase order record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I was searching for a value from contract record in Purchase record but i am unable to get the field where the value is. Below is the code for that. I am applying this code for the contract record and the function is for before submit.
I think I am applying the search in wrong way.

```
 function srchfield() 
 {

        var recordid = nlapiGetRecordId() //retunrs the contract id
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recordid ', recordid );

        var recordtype = nlapiGetRecordType();     //retunrs the contract recordtype = jobs   
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'RecordType', recordtype);

        var loadrecord = nlapiLoadRecord(recordtype, recordid); //loads the record
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Load Record', loadrecord );

        var contractname = nlapiGetFieldValue('entityid'); //returs the value of the field contractname whose fieldid is = entityid
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'ContractName ', contractname );


   var filters = new Array();
      new nlobjSearchFilter('entityid', null, 'anyof', contractname ); // entityid is field id in contract Record and contractname is defined above for contract record

          // nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'SearchFilter', filters );

  var columns = new Array();
  new nlobjSearchColumn('custbodycontract'); // custbodycontractis field id in PO Record


  var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('purchaseorder', null, filters, columns);


for ( var i = 0; searchresults != null && i < searchresults.length; i++ )
{
   var searchresult = searchresults[ i ];
   var record = searchresult.getId( );
   var rectype = searchresult.getRecordType( );
   var cntrct_name= searchresult.getValue( 'custbodycontract' );

}

 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify: You are searching POs by these contract entities, yet there is another PO field `custbodycontract`. What does that hold?

Comment: that is the field id of the field in PO in which i am searching the entities from the contract field

Comment: It holds the contract name

Answer (score 0):

****Update: I have completed my answer based on the comments provided. Please see at the last section. I hope it helps. Thanks!***

**I might provide you the snippet if you will explain this further. Please advise

If I understand correctly your code, these are what you are doing and you want to do:

- Your contract record is the native entity record - project/job. It had just been renamed to contract by your functional consultant.
- You have an user event script (SuiteScript 1.0) before submit and deployed to the contract (project/job) record.
- Using the information from the contract record (in this case using the contract name (entityid), you wanted to search for POs to get 'custbodycontract' at the header.
- Then you are filtering the search on POs using "entityid" but PO doesnt have that native field on the header. It only has it on the expense line and item line but the id is 'customer'.


  Can you explain how is the contract record related to PO. Which field (native/custom) is available on PO that can be used as a join on contract record?



  Then, please take note this best practice as freebie.

  1. To optimize your script. You don't need to use nlapiLoadRecord on beforesubmit. Please see below the best practice.:

         - With beforesubmit and if you are only getting or setting values on the script deployed record, use nlapiGet** and nlapiSet** API.

         - On beforesubmit, only use nlapiLoadRecord if you are getting and setting the value on the sublist of a different record. But utilize first nlapiSearchRecord if you are only getting value at the line level (different record). If it will not give what you need, use nlapiLoadRecord.

         - On aftersubmit, only use nlapiLoadRecord if you are setting and getting value at the line level of the deployed record and different record. If you are only getting value at the level, same practice with beforesubmit.

         - On aftersubmit, use nlapiLookUp for getting value from the header, and nlapiSubmitField if you are setting. Only use nlapiLoadRecord if it doesnt give you what you need.



     ****This might what you need...

```
function srchfield()
{
    var stRecordid = nlapiGetRecordId(); /*retunrs the contract id*/
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recordid ', stRecordid);

    var stRecordtype = nlapiGetRecordType(); /*retunrs the contract recordtype = jobs*/
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'RecordType', stRecordtype);

    var stContractname = nlapiGetFieldValue('entityid'); /*returs the value of the field contractname whose fieldid is = entityid*/
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'ContractName ', stContractname);

    var arrFilters = new Array();
    arrFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('type', null, 'anyof',
        [
            'PurchOrd'
        ])); /*As best practice, instead of directly searching on POs, add filter for transaction type since you might use this later in other transaction.*/
    arrFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T')); /*This is to exclude line level results*/
    arrFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('custbodycontract', null, 'is', stContractname));

    var arrColumns = new Array();
    arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('trandate')); /*I just wanted to include this column on the result. :)*/
    arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('type')); /*I just wanted to include this column on the result. :)*/
    arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid')); /*I just wanted to include this column on the result. :)*/
    arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('custbodycontract')); /*This is what you need.*/

    var arrSearchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, arrFilters, arrColumns);
```

```
for (var i = 0; arrSearchresults != null && i < arrSearchresults.length; i++)
{
    var objResult = arrSearchresults[i];
    var stRecId = objResult.getId();
    var stRecType = objResult.getRecordType();
    var stCntrctName = objResult.getValue('custbodycontract');
}
```

Comment: hello,

The contract record and the PO record are connected to each other by contract name. The internal id of this field on the contract record is "entityid" and on the PO record the internal ID is "custbodycontract"

Comment: Then an beforesubmit user event is deployed on a contract record. Right? Next is search for POs using the entityid?

Comment: Then take note the entityid will give you the text value not the internal id of the record, so I will presume the "custbodycontract" is freeform text field type. Please confirm.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comments and my presumption. Hope it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I notice on your code is the creation of the filter.
You instantiated nlobjSearchFilter but you didn't push it in an array. So basically, you are searching without filter. 
And I believe your search criteria were complete.
 
Try below codes. By the way make sure that the field type of custbodycontract is a freeform text to properly compare it with the entityid of the contract record.

```
function srchfield()
{
var stRecordid = nlapiGetRecordId(); /*retunrs the contract id*/
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recordid ', stRecordid);

var stRecordtype = nlapiGetRecordType(); /*retunrs the contract recordtype = jobs*/
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'RecordType', stRecordtype);

var stContractname = nlapiGetFieldValue('entityid'); /*returs the value of the field contractname whose fieldid is = entityid*/
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'ContractName ', stContractname);

var arrFilters = new Array();
arrFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('type', null, 'anyof',
    [
        'PurchOrd'
    ])); /*As best practice, instead of directly searching on POs, add filter for transaction type since you might use this later in other transaction.*/
arrFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T')); /*This is to exclude line level results*/
arrFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('custbodycontract', null, 'is', stContractname));

var arrColumns = new Array();
arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('trandate')); /*I just wanted to include this column on the result. :)*/
arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('type')); /*I just wanted to include this column on the result. :)*/
arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid')); /*I just wanted to include this column on the result. :)*/
arrColumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('custbodycontract')); /*This is what you need.*/

var arrSearchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, arrFilters, arrColumns);
for (var i = 0; arrSearchresults != null && i < arrSearchresults.length; i++)
{
    var objResult = arrSearchresults[i];
    var stRecId = objResult.getId();
    var stRecType = objResult.getRecordType();
    var stCntrctName = objResult.getValue('custbodycontract');
}
}
```